# Node.js Http request beforesent

Tags: node.js

In jQuery we have `beforeSend` method on ajax request.
Is there equivalent method in Node.js HTTP lib?

What I need is this: before the request is sent out I have to get the exact body (with boundries etc) then I need to sign it and add the signed value to header.

In jQuery I did it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: host + path,
    type: method,
    data: payload,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      addSecurityHeaders(xhr, payload)
    })
```

And my node.js code looks atm like this:

```
var request = require('request')


var req = request.post({
              url: host + path,
              headers: headers,
              multipart: {
                chunked: false,
                data: [
                  {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'fileName': 'file.png',
                    body: dataToBeSent
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, function (err, resp, body) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Error!');
              } else {
                console.log('URL: ' + body);
              }
            });
```

Comment: AFAIK, `http` sends the body you pass as it is, so you can sign it before you send the request. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It add boundries, if you make multipart/form-data request.

Comment: It seems you are using the `request` package, not `http` directly?

Comment: yes `var request = require('request')`

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/form-data/form-data directly.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple callback, that will be executed before you send the request ?

```
var beforeSend = function(arg, cb){
   // do some stuff 
   cb(dataToBeSend); // return the needed variable
};

beforeSend(arg ,function(dataToBeSend){
   request.post({
      // request parameters
      data : dataToBeSend
   }, function(err, resp, body){
      // error handling
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite rare usecase. So I'll put my solution here.
I `use request.Request.prototype.write` to get the request body parts that I need to sign. When it has added all 4 parts ja replace the header, that had `PLACEHOLDER` placed in it before, with the signed body. :)

```
var PLACEHOLDER = '______PLACEHOLDER______';
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
  var oldWriteFunction = request.Request.prototype.write;
  var header, content, spaces, footer;
  request.Request.prototype.write = function (data) { // builds up data
    var data = data.utf8Slice();
    if (!header) { // constructs the body of request - the part that is between boundaries and boundaries themselves.
      header = data;
    } else if (!content) {
      content = data;
    } else if (!spaces) {
      spaces = data;
    } else if (!footer) {
      footer = data;
    }
    if (footer) {
      var toSign = header + content + spaces + footer;
      this.req.output[0] = this.req.output[0].replace(PLACEHOLDER, sign(toSign));
    }
    oldWriteFunction.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  request.post({
    url: host + path,
    headers: getHeadersForFileUpload(),
    multipart: {
      chunked: false,
      data: [
        {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; fileName="file.png" ',
          body: ev.target.result
        }
      ]
    }
  }, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(body);
    }
    request.Request.prototype.write = oldWriteFunction; // but back correct funtion for others to use.
  });
});
reader.readAsDataURL(new File(optionsArg.file));
```